# Combining columns from one table into a single column in another?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables below parking_scans and parking_scans_1. I need to combine the two columns in parking_scans into the column in parking_scans_1.cap were section is between 1 and 2 in cap2014
and section is between 3 and 4 in cap2015.
I've tried this insert code but am not getting the result I am after.

```
INSERT INTO parking_scans_1(cap)
SELECT cap2014
FROM parking_scans
WHERE section BETWEEN '1' AND '2';
```

```
INSERT INTO parking_scans_1(cap)
SELECT cap2015
FROM parking_scans
WHERE section BETWEEN '3' AND '4';
```

Is there a good way to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE parking_scans 
   (
section_id int, 
cap2014 varchar
cap2015 varchar
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE parking_scans_1
(
section_id int
cap varchar
);
```

parking_scans:

| section | cap2014 | cap2015 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | null |
| 2 | 3 | null |
| 3 | null | 43 |
| 4 | null | 33 |

what I need is:

| section | cap |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 43 |
| 4 | 33 |

Comment: Union all, group by.

Comment: `INSERT INTO parking_scans_1(cap) SELECT cap2014 
FROM parking_scans as ps WHERE section_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2 AND cap IS NOT NULL AND ps.section_id = section_id;`. Repeat for  `cap2015` and `section_id BETWEEN 3 AND 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are inserting twice, appending to your table.

Try inserting one time:

```
INSERT INTO parking_scans_1(cap)
SELECT CASE WHEN section BETWEEN '1' AND '2' THEN cap2014
WHEN section BETWEEN '3' AND '4' THEN cap2015 END
FROM parking_scans
```